# Not able to display the return data from service to html view in Angular.

Tags: angular, rest, observable

In my angular2 application, I am trying to use a Github service and trying to display the return data on UI.

In first try I got an error as "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. " I figured the reason of the error and created a custom pipe to convert the object to array but still I am not able to bind the data to UI.

**Service code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs'

export interface GitHubUser
{
  html_url:string;
  avatar_url:string;
  login:string;
  score:string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyserviceService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  getGitHubData(_searchTerm):Observable<GitHubUser[]>{
    return this._http.get<GitHubUser[]>
    ("https://api.github.com/search/users?q="+_searchTerm);
  }
}
```

**pipe code**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'derp' })
export class DerpPipe {
  transform (value, args) {
    return Array.from(value);
  }
}
```

**App.component.ts**

```
constructor(private _obj:MyserviceService){//(private _githubService:GitHubServiceService1){

   this.data$= this._obj.getGitHubData('gaurav');
   this.data$.subscribe(users=> {
      this.users=users;
      console.log(this.users);
  });
```

**.html file**

```
*ngFor="let user of users | derp"
        {{ user.score }}
```

Comment: what are you getting in console.log(this.users);

Comment: In console.log , I am getting all results which is good. But I like to print that data on UI. so I am trying to use that object in for loop and not able to get any data.

Comment: post what you got in console

Comment: Array like below - {total_count: 10732, incomplete_results: false, items: Array(30)}
incomplete_results: false
items: Array(30)
0: {login: "gaurav", id: 23979, node_id: "MDQ6VXNlcjIzOTc5", avatar_url: "https:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service returns an object and an array nested inside it - i just try to hit your service on browser and found it - so your inerface should be something in that format

**GitHubUser object**

```
{
  total_count: number,
  incomplete_results: boolean,
  items: Users[]
}
```

So your users object should be in this format - i am just binding some of the properties if you want you can bind everything

**Users object**

```
{
   score : string,
   type : string,
   site_admin : boolean
}
```

Then in your service - which returns only a object not a array just change your return type as `GitHubUser` and `Observable<GitHubUser>` and in your component the user should be a object of type `GitHubUser`

It should read like this - `user: Users[]` and after binding your array in your component like this

```
this.service.getGitHubData("gaurav").subscribe((res) => {
     this.users = res.items;

   })
```

Finally html should read as

```
*ngFor="let user of users"
        {{ user.score }}
```

I have removed the pipe from your html - thus you might get your score - hope thos helps - happy coding :)

**Update**

I have slightly changed my answer check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-daopco?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) the working version

Comment: Thanks Rahul but still the same issue. Without pipe , I am getting below error - ppComponent.html:18 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. and with pipe , it is not giving any error but not printing anything in view.

Comment: Rahul: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting results as nested array, Your **`ngFor`** should look something like this,

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
        <li>
             <ul *ngFor="let info of user.items">
            <li>{{info | json}}</li>  //here you can access properties
       </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. But no luck. I used below but still nothing is getting printed on view - 
<ul *ngFor="let user of users | derp"> 
  <li>
       <ul *ngFor="let info of user.items">
      <li> {{info.login | json }} </li>  
 
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: you do not have to use the pipe

Comment: just remove |derp

Comment: I tried that way as well. If I do not use pipe , I will get error as - Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: are you sure you are getting an array as response?

Comment: Partial response as below - {total_count: 10733, incomplete_results: false, items: Array(30)}
incomplete_results: false
items: Array(30)
0: {login: "gaurav", id: 23979, node_id: "MDQ6VXNlcjIzOTc5", avatar_url: "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/23979?v=4", gravatar_id: "", …}
1: {login: "gauravssnl", id: 13808299, node_id: "MDQ6VXNlcjEzODA4Mjk5", avatar_u